# Populating an HTML table from Django views.py

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have an HTML table that I want to be populated from views.py. Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
{% for item in pizza %}
   <tr id="{{ item.name }}">
       <td>{{ item.status }}</td>
       <td>{{ item.name }}</td>           
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def pizza(request):
   pizza_data = [{'name': 'Pepperoni Pizza', 'status': 'Ready'}]
   return render(request, "index.html", {'pizza': pizza_data})
```

The table doesn't get populated and I don't see any error code. Is it the format in `pizza_data`? I removed the other `{% for %}` loop because Lucas is right that the other loop is useless.

I think I should say that `index.html` is inside a folder named `templates`. Not sure if this will affect because I declared the `STATIC_DIR` into this folder.

The reason why `pizza_data` is hardcoded is because that is a JSON file that I need to figure out how to insert but for now I want to see if the `{% for %}` loop can populate but it is not.

Comment: What do you mean by `{% for item in pizza.pizza.all %} `?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM apologies that was supposed to be from `def pizza(request)`. I wrote the wrong method name. (Also apologies the @ doesnt seem to work?? I've been trying to tag you but it wouldn't let me)

Comment: There are two errors, you are using the same variable name in your first loop `{% for pizza in pizza %}` and also trying to access a dictionary using  QuerySets methods `{% for item in pizza.pizza.all %}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it's working

#### views.py

```
def pizza(request):
   pizza_data = [{'name': 'Pepperoni Pizza', 'status': 'Ready'}]
   return render(request, "index.html", {'pizza_data': pizza_data})
```

#### HTML Table

```
<table class="table ">
  <thead>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for item in pizza_data %}
    <tr id="{{ item.name }}">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.status }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Output in Browser

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename your variable i think. And the second loop is useless, your put a dictionary in context, so you just need to access by key of each element:

```py
def pizza(request):
   pizza_data = [{'name': 'Pepperoni Pizza', 'status': 'Ready'}]
   return render(request, "index.html", {'pizzas': pizza_data})
```

```html
{% for pizza in pizzas %}
   <tr id="{{pizza.name}}">
       <td>{{pizza.status}}</td>
       <td>{{pizza.name}}</td>           
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello! You are right that the other for loop is useless so I removed it. For some reason it is still not showing up. Is it related to my `index.html` being located inside `templates` folder?

Comment: The second loop is not useless, what if the dictionary had twenty keys? It helps in not accessing every field manually.

Comment: @Niko The dictionnary has not twenty keys, just two. do not try to find solution for non existent problem

Comment: @fireblazer10 I made an error in the name of pizzaz instead of pizzas in the view's context, I fix it

Answer (score 1):

Your code at least shows result, However If you get *template does not exist error* It has another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.items`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) to loop through the dictionary:

```py
{% for obj in pizza %}
   <tr id="{{ obj.name }}">
       {% for key, value in obj.items %}
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
       {% endfor %}
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```